# How to prevent same file upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

I am new to laravel. I am trying to upload multiple files, but when I try to upload the same filenames at the same time, it crashes. how to prevent uploading same image names.

What I have tried is:

Html code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/listingSave" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="sellingFormSave" id="sellingFormSave" onsubmit="validate();">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 section_title-js">
            <h3></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input id="demo" type="file" name="files" accept=".jpg, .png, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>

        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit">
            Save
    </button>
</form>
```

Controller.php

```
public function listingSave(Request $request) {
   if(array_key_exists('image', $request->all())){
        
      $imageName = $request->imageName;
     
      $image = $request->image;
        foreach ($image as $key => $value) {         
          $image_name = date('mdYhis').'_'.$imageName[$key]; 
           
          $imgdata = base64_decode($value);
          $myOutput = public_path().'/app/default/files-module/local/images/'.$image_name;
          $ifp = fopen( $myOutput, 'wb' ); 
          fwrite( $ifp, $imgdata );
          fclose( $ifp );    
          $imageInfo = getimagesize($myOutput);
          $files = FileModel::updateOrCreate(['name'=>$image_name],[
              // 'sort_order'=>$truckian->id+$key,
              'sort_order'=>0+$key,
              'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              'updated_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              // 'created_by_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
              'created_by_id'=>0,
              'disk_id'=>1,
              'folder_id'=>1,
              'extension'=>str_replace('image/', '', $imageInfo['mime']),
              'size'=>$imageInfo[0]*$imageInfo[1],
              'mime_type'=>$imageInfo['mime'],
              "entry_type" => "Anomaly\Streams\Platform\Model\Files\FilesImagesEntryModel",
              "height" => $imageInfo[1],
              "width" => $imageInfo[0],
            ]);
          // DB::table('truckian_products_image')->insert(['entry_id'=>$truckian->id,'file_id'=>$files->id,'sort_order'=>$key+1]);
          DB::table('truckian_products_image')->insert(['entry_id'=>$p_id,'file_id'=>$files->id,'sort_order'=>$key+1]);
        }
        foreach($available as $key => $value)
        DB::insert('insert into default_truckian_mileage_gap(mileage_gap,number_of_products,truck_id)values (?,  ?, ?)',[$key,$value,$p_id]);
    }


}
```

Whenever I execute same file names, it crashes. How to fix this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Dula  Yes I am getting like this . SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '40-8897' for key 'c72333b5ba020bf52db5233c89a40c13' (SQL: insert into `default_truckian_products_image` (`entry_id`, `file_id`, `sort_order`) values (40, 8897, 2))

Comment: I think the error is generated from the place where you are trying to insert data to ``default_truckian_products_image`` table.

Comment: @Dula No, it has no error, when unique names are uploading, but when I try to upload same images , this error occur.

Comment: there may be constrain added for id and file name in you DB. You should remove it from table schema OR try to append some random name to file name

Answer (score 0):

Try to use incrementor variable like below in defining file name in foreach loop

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($image as $key => $value) {         
      $image_name = date('mdYhis').'_'.$i.'_'.$imageName[$key];
      //other code
      $i++;
}
```

It will create different names for file everytime even if its uploaded at same time